# fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <class 'main.SoluteSolvent'> is a valid pydantic field type

Tags: python, fastapi

getting this error while executing the fast API code `fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <class 'main.SoluteSolvent'> is a valid pydantic field type`

```py
class SoluteSolvent():
    solvent: Text
    solute: Text

response = {}
@app.get('/predict')
def predict(sol:SoluteSolvent):
    data = sol.dict()
    solute = data['solute']
    solvent = data['solvent']
    results = predictions(solute, solvent)
    print(results)
    response["predictions"] = results[0].item()
    response["interaction_map"] = (results[1].detach().numpy()).tolist()
    return {'result':response}
```

I was actually trying to replicate the code I have written for prediction in flask in fast API.

```py
response = {}
@app.route('/predict', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def predict():
    if request.method=='POST':
        solute = request.form["solute"]
        solvent = request.form["solvent"]

    else:
        solute = request.args.get("solute")
        solvent = request.args.get("solvent")

    results = predictions(solute, solvent)
    
    response["predictions"] = results[0].item()
    response["interaction_map"] = (results[1].detach().numpy()).tolist()
    return flask.jsonify({'result': response})
```

Answer (score 13):

The error says your type you pass to `predict` must be pydantic [BaseModel](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/features/#just-modern-python) (or [dataclass](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/dataclasses/) from 0.67.0 version of FastApi). However it won't work that way (at least on get request), if you want to pass query params (suggested solution) list them in function:

```
@app.get('/predict')
def predict(solute: str, solvent: str):
   print(solute, solvent)
```

And use model for post request (which expects data in body):

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
class SoluteSolvent(BaseModel):
    solvent: str
    solute: str

@app.post('/predict')
def predict(sol:SoluteSolvent):
    print(sol.solute)
```

Or you can use underlying [starlette Request](https://www.starlette.io/requests/#query-parameters) directly

```
from fastapi import Request

async def predict(r: Request):
    print(r.query_params["solute"])
```